# Split a string, and save sub strings in array

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a string that is something like this:

```
(InstrTyp EQ DebtInstruments) AND (IntrnlTrdTyp EQ IntraGrpBP) AND (Entity EQ GSSTH)
```

I would like to save these in an array such that :

- 1st element : `InstrTyp EQ DebtInstruments`
- 2nd element : `IntrnlTrdTyp EQ IntraGrpBP`
- 3rd element : `Entity EQ GSSTH`

New to PL/SQL, appreciate a verbose answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `regexp_substr` to extract the string between parentheses

```
DECLARE
     TYPE string_array_typ IS
          TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
     split_strs       string_array_typ := string_array_typ(); --define and declare an array of string
     l_str_to_split   VARCHAR2(1000) := '(InstrTyp EQ DebtInstruments) AND (IntrnlTrdTyp EQ IntraGrpBP) AND (Entity EQ GSSTH)'
     ;
BEGIN 
FOR i IN 1..regexp_count(l_str_to_split,'\(.*?\)')  --loop until as many number of strings between `()`
  LOOP 
   split_strs.extend;
   split_strs(i) := regexp_substr(l_str_to_split,'\((.*?)\)',1,i,NULL,1); -- Assign ith element to ith word between `()`
 END loop;

 FOR i IN 1..split_strs.count LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line(split_strs(i) ); --display the contents of the array
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try doing this in two steps.  First, remove all parentheses from the input string, then do a regex split to array on the pattern `\s*AND\s*`:

```
select
    regexp_split_to_array(regexp_replace(txt, '[()]', '', 'g'), '\s*AND\s*')
from your_table;
```

[image]

### Demo